# php-Codeigniter url not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a project inside /htdocs/trunk folder. Codeigniter folder structure such as 'application', 'system' etc exist inside trunk. Below is .htaccess file which is inside /htdocs/trunk/application:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Below is my config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/trunk/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

When I open the base url above in the browser, I successfully get my login page. However, when I click on anchor link which calls the controller function, I get 403 Forbidden. Below is routes, view and error:-

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "chomecontroller";
$route['search'] = "csearchentrycontroller";
$route['search/(:any)'] = "csearchentrycontroller/$1";
```

**view**

```
<a href="<? echo base_url();?>search/searchEntry/4/1"> Redirect here </a>
```

**error**

```
You don't have permission to access /trunk/< on this server.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so You would have skip the index.php in between the URL.
Please include index.php in between URL and check whether its working or not.

Ex: http://localhost:90/codeigniter_captcha/index.php/{controller_name}.

After that if you want to skip index.php in between URL change it in Config File.